# Why is NaCl so abundant in the ocean

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, halides

Why is sodium chloride far and away the most abundant salt dissolved in ocean water. Its two constituent ions do have a very high frequency in the crust of the earth but they are far from the most common. Chlorine is (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine)) the 21st most abundant element, and [sodium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium) 6th.

I certainly understand that a combination of their solubility and reasonably high frequency would lead one to expect them to but abundant in sea water, but they are hyper abundant, completely dominating all other salt ions. Iron, for example, is twice as abundant, and potassium only a little less abundant, fluorine more abundant than chlorine.

Moreover, if the salts are deposited in the ocean through weathering of rocks and deposition via rivers, why does the salinity not simply grow and grow? I understand that some is lost due to tectonic activity, but it seems extraordinarily unlikely that these two forces should be equally balanced, and so we would see a significant change in average salinity over time.

Comment: Umm, this is Chemistry.SE, not Earth Science and even there this would be probably too broad.

Comment: BTW this is pretty obvious that there **is** an equilibrium in processes that lower and increase these concentrations. Even if they were changing, it would just mean the equilibrium is shifting.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawater#Origin_and_history

Comment: Reactivity is also an factor. Abundance of iron might be high but it doesn't have enough reactivity to form sufficient salts.

Comment: Rather than at the abundance of the elements look for the most abundant salts at surface level. It should than fit. At least we can expect that the most abundant and soluble salt accessible to "runningc water is NaCl.

Comment: This is a very interesting question but better suited for earth science SE. An online search might help too: https://www.whoi.edu/science/GG/geodynamics/2005/images2005/holland04_treatise.pdf

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on earth science SE